# output is not continuously changing in 2x4 decoder testbench

Tags: verilog

my 2x4 decoder code:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module decoder(in,out);
   input [1:0]in;
    output [3:0]out;
    reg [3:0]out;
always@(in)
    begin

            case(in)
                2'b00:out = 4'b0001;
                2'b01:out = 4'b0010;
                2'b10:out = 4'b0100;
                2'b11:out = 4'b1000;


                default:out = 4'b1111;
        endcase


        end
    endmodule
```

// **I have written behavior code for 2x4 decoder and test bench. What I am seeing in my output is only it is showing me the output at 11...which is 0011. I want to see output changing continuously whenever my input is changing.

```
can any body show my mistake ??**
```

piece of code//

```
 `timescale 1ns / 100ps


        module decoder_t;

          reg [1:0]in;
          wire [3:0] out;



    decoder decoder1 ( .in(in),.out(out) );

    initial 
       begin

    #10 in=2'b00;
    #10 in=2'b01;
    #10 in=2'b10;
    #10 in=2'b11;


    #10 $stop;

       end

    endmodule
```

Comment: This code looks fine. The issue is (probably) in decoder module itself. Show us its code.

Comment: yes, the testbench code looks fine. I too feel that the issue may be with the decoder module.share ur code here.

Answer (score 2):

The Verilog runs as expected. Best guess is the user is observing the value of `in` and `out` at `$stop` and not before. My recommendation is to add a `$monitor` statement to report the value changes.

For example, add `$monitor("%t: in:%b out:%b", $realtime, in, out);` just before `#10 in=2'b00;` in the test bench. Then the log file will include the following:

```
     0: in:xx out:xxxx
   100: in:00 out:0001
   200: in:01 out:0010
   300: in:10 out:0100
   400: in:11 out:1000
```

---

**Update: waveform dumping**

Assuming you are dumping to a standard value change dump (VCD) file as defined in all version of IEEE Std 1364 and IEEE Std 1800. Add `$dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;` before driving the stimulus (i.e. just before `#10 in=2'b00;`). Refer to IEEE Std 1364-1995 section 15 (section 18 for newer version of IEEE 1364), or [IEEE Std 1800-2012 (available for free from IEEE)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) section 21.7, to see usage of all `$dump*` system tasks.

If you are using a different tool for waveform generation, then refer to the manual. 97% chance the placement of the system task(s) will need to be called before driving the stimulus, just like `$dumpvars` and `$monitor.`

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot ..That I know to see in monitor window. But I just wanted to see the same output in waveform also. Do you have any suggestion how can I see in waveform ??

Comment: @user2312332 , I have updated my answer with standard VCD instructions.